# Templated class syntax errors

Tags: c++, templates, debugging, syntax, syntax-error

I have these tree classes.

A `ListTraits.h` , a `List.h` and `main.cpp`

`List.h` is a templated implementation of list, and it inherits from `ListTraits.h`

While I believe that my setup for the templated class is correct,

I get several syntax errors, that do not seem like they should be there:

Specifically, for the `Listh.h` I get:

`(line 8)` ..

```
Node<typename>* head;
```

### Error   C2143   syntax error: missing ';' before '<'    main

### Error   C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int    main

And then a series of other errors but these two make the least sense.

These are my files.

List.h

```
    #pragma once
#include "ListTraits.h"
//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test1 in main.cpp

template <typename> class List: public ListTraitsExtended<typename>, 
                                public ListTraits<typename> {
private:
    Node<typename>* head;
public:
    List() {head = NULL;}
    
    unsigned int size() {return 0;}

    ListTraits& insert(const typename& item) {return null;}

    void print() {}
//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test2 in main.cpp
    const typename* getCurrentElement() const {}

    void advance() {}

    void rewind() {}
};
```

ListTraits.h

```
    #pragma once

//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test1 in main.cpp
template <typename T> class ListTraits
{
    public:
        virtual unsigned int size() = 0;
        virtual ListTraits& insert(const T& item) = 0;
        virtual void print() = 0;
};

//------------ Declarations for List traits used in Test2 in main.cpp
template <typename T> class ListTraitsExtended
{
    public:
        virtual const T* getCurrentElement() const = 0;
        virtual void advance() = 0;
        virtual void rewind() = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`typename` is a **keyword**, not the actual name of a type.

In `List.h` when you derived from `ListTraitsExtended<typename>` and `ListTraitsExtended<typename>`, and use `Node<typename>`, you are causing syntax errors since these template expect the name of a **type** to be passed to it, and you're passing it a **keyword**.

You should give a name to the primary template of `List`, such as changing it to `template <typename T>`, and then pass the named type `T` to each template instead:

```cpp
template <typename T> class List: public ListTraitsExtended<T>, 
//                 ^ name it here                           ^ use it here
                                  public ListTraits<T> {
//                                                  ^ use it here
private:
    Node<T>* head;
//       ^ and here
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Though the error ::::
Error C2143 syntax error: missing ';' before '<'"           is still there

Comment: Also in :::::  Node<T>* head;   :::::: at line 8 I get an error saying that ::: 'head' identifier not found

Comment: @C96 To be blunt, you might have a lot of syntax errors -- but it's going to be easier to address these individually with your compiler. An "identifier not found" sounds like you haven't declared something in the name scope, and a "missing ;" sounds like you're missing a semicolon somewhere.